# Draggable Frame/Slider

Tags: swiftui

This is probably a rookie mistake, but I'm trying to create an "expandable" frame in SwiftUI, i.e. a frame that could be extended via a draggable "slider". I'm thinking that the easiest way could be specifying a frame, and a rectangle as "slider" to drag.

Here's an MRE:

```
import SwiftUI

fileprivate enum Constants {
    static let radius: CGFloat = 16
    static let indicatorHeight: CGFloat = 6
    static let indicatorWidth: CGFloat = 60
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @GestureState private var dragAmount = CGSize.zero
    private var frameheight : CGFloat = 200
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
        Text("Hello, world!")
                .frame(height: frameheight + dragAmount.height)
        Divider()
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: Constants.radius)
            .fill(Color.secondary)
            .frame(
                width: Constants.indicatorWidth,
                height: Constants.indicatorHeight
            )
            .gesture(
                DragGesture().updating($dragAmount) { value, state, transaction in
                    state = value.translation
                    print("Height: \(state), drag Amount: \(dragAmount)")
                }
                )
            Divider()
            Text("Hello, world!")
            Text("Hello, world!")
            Spacer()
            
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Looks ok... but it doesn't work. When I move the mouse up and down, my "print" statement indicates that dragAmount changes, but my frame size doesn't. Interestingly, changing  "+ dragAmount.height" to " + dragAmount.width" *does* change the height, but only temporarily... and only if you drag the rectangle left/right.

Any insights why? And, of course, suggestions how to fix are welcome! :)

Thanks, Philipp

Comment: When you stop dragging, the drag offset goes back to zero. You have to actually have to store the changed amount for the frame to stay. Look up PreferenceKeys. There are tons of answers that will show you how to ue them.

Comment: I tried your approach, it is in infinity loop kind of! I tried a different approach than your approach, but my approach is completely other thing, if you can change your approach, I could gave an approach for you: https://vm.tiktok.com/ZML5Gf28c/?k=1

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59540581/12299030?